# Use multi classification after splitting data for binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I would like to test the performance of the binary and multi classification ML techniques on the same split data.
I have already split my data to X & Y and my independent variable Y was a binary label.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X_normalized, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

Now I would like to change the Y to a multi class independent variable. How can I do this and use the same split data to achieve a fair comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [ShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html) which returns train / test indices to split data.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
import numpy as np

X_normalized = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(100, 16))
Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(100,))

cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
train_idx, test_idx = next(cv.split(X_normalized, Y))

X_train, y_train = X_normalized[train_idx], Y[train_idx]
X_test, y_test = X_normalized[test_idx], Y[test_idx]
print(test_idx)

# Now change the y-s
Y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100,))
y_train, y_test = Y[train_idx], Y[test_idx]
print(test_idx)
```

`train_test_split` uses the same ShuffleSplit class under the hood:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/df626e43ac3c99da2aeb005709d77395bd717e6a/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2579

but ShuffleSplit is more flexible